# Install MPICH & OpenMPI with both gcc and icc

Tags: macos, gcc, mpi, gnu, icc

I need to have the following 4 options

OpenMPI running with gcc and icc
MPICH running with gcc and icc

Is there any good to way/practice to achieve this without screwing up your system. I am on a MacOS using homebrew

Comment: Have a look at spack.

Comment: Or you can always install [Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/index.html) and make your Mac feel like a real HPC system :) It is available as a Homebrew recipe called `modules`.